# Ubuntu crashes on default session on kernel 5.8 (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: kernel, xorg, hardware-enablement-stack

My ubuntu 20.04 got updated to kernel 5.8 (via hwe i guess), and when i use the default ubuntu session it doesn't work, when i log into my user, it goes to the desktop, but after a brief time it just goest back to the login page. I tried using the wayland session and it does work and wayland apps open just fine, but when i need to use something that uses xwayland (like firefox, or gimp snap) it doesn't work either.

Kernel 5.4 works just fine (using the grub advanced options to select it), is the best option to just keep using 5.4, or is there any solution?

Comment: You're rather light on specifics; "*Apps don't work*" lacks details of what applications, if they crashed, if there were any clues in the .crash files etc.  Yes using the GA (general) kernel is an option as it's supported the life of the product (my 20.04 system still uses the GA kernel), but I'd explore why you're "apps are crashing" as that doesn't seem right to me; as if you've missed something more serious.

Comment: For example, in the wayland session gnome apps like nautilus, gnome terminal, the calculator, etc works just fine but gimp (snap), firefox ( default .deb) never open.

In default session it doesn't let me do anything, it just goes back to the user login, where can i search for those files?. PD: i don't have nvidia nor amd gpu, just intel integrated graphics)